# Text should be kept in ppt, pdf, or on html pages to get more SEO benefits and good results at SERP

Tags: seo

I am going to build a website. Now my question which is the best option for text to be displayed. It should be kept in ppt, pdf, or on html pages to get more SEO benefits and good results at SERP

Answer (score 7):

While search engines have gotten really good at searching in ppt, pdf, doc and other formats, html is the format of the web.  You can't assume that your end users will have the software to read ppt, doc, pdf etc.

Good ranking algorithms put the user first.  The more you make your web site useful to users, the better your search ranking will be, and the more accessible you make your content, the better.

All that to say: use html for your text as often as it makes sense.

Taking this a little further:

I would really only use pdfs and ppts when I want someone to download a file that they will use in the intended program; like a ppt for a presentation I have put together for other educators to use.  If I want people to read or learn from something I have created for direct consumption, I would use html.  Even if I was offering file downloads, I would consider placing some or all of the key content in html.